# Server Manipulation using Linode Manager or other techniques to develop a mirror site

Tags: webserver, web-testing, linode

A quick question, does anyone know how I can take an address say www.google.com and create a mirror site such as www.newsite.google.com ?

I'm a beginner when it comes to server testing and server manipulation. I normally just drag and drop through SFTP/FTP.

Any ideas or thoughts?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: Do you really want an exact mirror of (using this example) www.google.com?  Or do you just want some other URL to redirect to www.google.com?

Comment: I was using google as an example, i've found out that I need to use apache vshosts to get the desired sub-domain, nothing to do with google haha

Comment: Right, but do you want a full copy of the site, or just a redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of tips from a former colleague, we sat down and talked about this issue.

First of all we mentioned APACHE VHOSTS - needed to add a directory for my sub domain, e.g. new.google.com

To do this I had to SSH the server and perform sudo, vim and a range of commmands on directories and files.

As I use linode manger, I had to add an A record to make the sub domain active/work.

All now works and I have a new sub domain.